# In python, is the 'for' function interactive x factor and y factor?

Tags: python

I am new in python, so i used to practice some.
I tried;

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> y = x

>>> for i in range(0, len(x)):
...     y[i] = x[i]**2
...
>>> y
[1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> x
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

My problem :
I can't understand why `x` is changed,too.

I just expected `y` like this : `y = [1, 4, 9, 16]` (yes, it works in right way)

But, you see, `x` is also changed : `x = [1, 4, 9, 16]` (this makes me embarrassing)

How can i fix my mistake?

Comment: when you do `y = x` for non-primitive types, they are alias to the same objects in Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent

Comment: In order to make a 'copy' of the list, rather than referencing the same one, you could do `y = [*x]`

Comment: Do `y = x[  :  ]`. read more about `shallow copy` and `deep copy` from here https://www.python-course.eu/python3_deep_copy.php

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia It doesn't matter if the type is primitive, it does this for all objects.

Comment: It wouldn't override `x` if `y` is changed and `x` is of `int` type; would it?

Comment: @Krishna You just can't *mutate* an int, i.e. there's no `42.value = 69` or anything like that. You can only assign a *new int object* to `y`.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia http://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `y = x`, they are alias to the same objects in Python.

Try this if you don't want `x` to be changes when `y` changes:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = x.copy()

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    y[i] = x[i]**2
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: it works! thx :)

Comment: Awesome @ELLO, please consider accepting the answer if it resolves your query.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to make a shallow copy of the variable `x`.

```
>>>x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>y = x[:]

>>> for i in range(0, len(x)):
...     y[i] = x[i]**2
...
>>> y
[1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: it works! thx :)

Answer (score 1):

In the second line, `y = x`, you made `x` and `y` point to the same list, so when you mutated `y`, it mutated `x` also. To fix this simply change that line to `y = []`. But now we got a different problem, `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`, to fix this, instead of assigning to `y[i]`, we'll use `y.append`:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = []
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    y.append(x[i]**2)
```

**Output:**

```py
x == [1, 2, 3, 4]
y == [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Note that with this we no longer need `i`, only `x[i]`, so we can iterate over `x` instead:

```py
for item in x:
    y.append(item**2)
```

Comment: It makes another problems:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: @ELLO I've edited the answer to acount for that, refresh your page.